# how do I diagnose why a process is starting?

Tags: upstart, systemd, ubuntu-core, deluge, background-process

I'm running an ubuntu box, mainly as a learning exercise, so I should probably begin by stating that I'm still very much at the "copying commands until something works" stage of unix knowledge. I recently upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04, and since that upgrade I've been having an issue with the daemon for the deluge torrent client.

When I upgraded to 15.04, I followed the 'official' instructions for moving the `deluged` daemon over to systemd. As part of this process, I believe I deleted the old upstart configurations associated with this service. In both my previous and my new configuration, I'm launching the daemon under my own user account (launching it under a 'deluge' user caused problems for me when I first installed) - and this works, except for one issue.

Despite my .service file being correct for the configuration I want, and despite this service starting normally and working fine when i do `systemctl start deluged`, I'm not able to start the service unless I kill an instance of `deluged` that is running at boot under the `root` user account. I don't want it to run as root, and as far as I'm aware, I've never configured it to do so - and this instance of the daemon obviously prevents my desired instance from starting up. I obviously don't want it running as root, partly because I know it's a bad idea, but also because it prevents the thin client from actually being able to connect.

Tl;dr: How can I work out what is causing this service to launch on startup as root, and how do I prevent it from doing so, so that I'm able to start the daemon properly without first having to manually kill the unwanted instance after each reboot? I have deleted all existing configs before following instructions, and as far as I know `upstart` and `init.d` are no longer active on my system anyway. There is a possibility that I did something dumb when I first installed that I don't remember, as deluge was one of the first things I configured on my first ever unix installation.

(For anyone kind enough to provide an answer, my current unix competence is at the level of knowing whether a process/daemon is running, understanding and manually editing config files, a beginner understanding of how to interpret logs, and basically no understanding at all of the deeper concepts at work behind the scenes.)

Comment: You can disable that from running at boot with `systemctl disable unit` but as far as running services as regular user . . . I somewhat doubt its possible

Comment: The deluged daemon runs just fine under my own account, it just won't automatically start because another instance keeps launching as root first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this doesn't seem to be that common a problem, and to resolve this after all this time, I'm answering my own question – turns out that the process was being started in `/etc/rc.local`, which was really stupid of me (and it's also fairly stupid that I didn't think to check there).

So, if there's any lesson to be learned here, it's to enumerate every possible way a fault can occur and then check the possibilities one by one, no matter how stupid, and no matter whether or not you think you already checked there.

Comment: `rc.local` was my first thought, especially given it started as root. Good catch, anyway!

Comment: The irony is that the only reason i opened rc.local was to add a script that would `pkill deluge` followed by `systemctl start deluged` lmao

Comment: @Toadfish: could you click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: i thought it would be gauche to approve my own answer, but I failed to consider that it also serves the purpose of closing the question, hah